# Sum Function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Evening all:

I am trying to sum number values from a column based off a value from a different.  How can I do this?  =Sum(A)?  I want to add the values of A based off the 10 from B.

Here is a simple screen shot of what I want to try to do:

[image]

Comment: For future reference basic formulae questions should be asked at [su]

Comment: @pnuts Nope, not completely :) By and large you will see basic formula questions closed and migrated by the regulars, some of the more advanced formula questions are stickier. Part of this relates to history when prior to SU there was only SO for formula questions. But given the broader Excel community clearly differentiates between VBA/non-VBA  as programming/using software I think migration of such questions is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SUMIF` to accomplish what I believe you are going for. In cell `C1` in your example:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B1,A:A)
```

That would put the sum next to each occurrence of the value in column B. You could copy only the uniques from column B and do the same if that is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: @Jeff Awesome, glad to hear it :)